# PHP only running in local network with apache2

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, apache2, local-network

So I am currently trying to get a apache2 server going. Html pages run fine, domain is set to my home ip, it's portforwarded and everything works fine.

Current issue is that php scripts only run when I try to acces the server from the local network.
I tried installing wordpress first, which worked fine for me, but then when I tried to acces it from a different network I got a connection time out.

So I replaced it with the basic php info page and I am running into the same issue.
[results from a local pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aztzT.png)

Could anyone weigh in, I have been struggling with this for days now :(

my httpd.conf only consists of the following:

```
<VirtualHost :80> 
    #ServerName ayz-abc.mysite.com/ 
    # Other directives here 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain.yt$ 
    RewriteRule /.
```

Comment: Normally Apache installs with the security set so you can only access it from the PC you installed it on. Stops beginners getting hacks in the first 10 minutes :) So you are going to have to hit the Apache manuals and research how apache limits who can access it. HINT: look in the httpd.conf file for something like `<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">` and in there for something like `require local` then research the require syntax to allow access to only your local network

Comment: WARNING: Do not find this section `<Directory />` and change anything in there.

Comment: Okay thanks! I did not know require local was a property.

my httpd.conf only consists of the following:

<VirtualHost *:80>

#ServerName ayz-abc.mysite.com/

 # Other directives here
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain.yt$
 RewriteRule /.* http://mydomain.yt/ [R]

</VirtualHost>